# I am facing issue on angular application build with sonarqube in Azure Devops

Tags: angular, sonarqube, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am new to sonarqube build definition process in azure devops, Based on some tutorials i have configured the build steps where in as per the below screenshot. I cannot further proceed and generate sonarqube report. Did anyone face similar issue, any suggestions would be helpful.

I have included the advanced sonar properties in the Prepare analysis on sonarqube step in my build definition.

Run code analysis error:

[image]

Comment: the error message actually tells a lot, you do not have java installed, and the sonar-scanner you are using is relying on java. If you do have java installed you just need to set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to your path.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this on how do i set the JAVA_HOME and how do i configure sonar-scanner in angular 6 application. I have followed the additional properties in my build definition using a tutorial sonar.host.url=<my-sonarqube.server>
sonar.projectKey=my.project.key
sonar.projectName=My Project Name
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=projects/project-a/src,projects/project-b/src
sonar.exclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.file.suffixes=.ts
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=out/coverage/lcov.info